# Comparing Model Fit: Poisson vs. Quasi-Poisson

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, count-data

I want to model some count data. I noticed that I have some under-dispersion (mean is 1.3, variance is 0.8), so I have seen some threads suggesting a quasi-poisson model. Is it possible to somehow compare these models and establish which one provides a better fit? I believe the quasi-poisson model does not have an associated AIC value with it, so I need to thing of another method.

Here is a histogram showing my outcome:
[image]

Comment: How much data do you have?  What are you modeling?

Comment: My data is roughly 140k rows. I am modeling the # of medications someone has received

Comment: Do you have any zeroes in your data, or does the data only contain observations of people who receive at least one medication?

Comment: I've updated my post to show the distribution of my outcome. There are zeroes in my outcome variable

Comment: What is your sample frame?  In the population at large, of course, there are far more zeroes than anything else... I'm wondering, obviously, if your sample is biased away from observing zeroes, which would a) increase the observed mean, and b) possibly decrease the observed variance relative to what you would see with an unbiased sample.

Comment: Please add new information as edits to the post, and not only as comments. Comments on this site are ephemeral, might be deleted, and often not seen by many!